How to style Flowbite React Components in React(issue with Tabs component)
<Tabs aria-label="Tabs with underline" variant="underline">
            <Tabs.Item active title="Profile" icon={HiUserCircle}>
              This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Profile tab's associated content</span>.
              Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
              control the content visibility and styling.
            </Tabs.Item>
            <Tabs.Item title="Dashboard" icon={MdDashboard}>
              This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Dashboard tab's associated content</span>.
              Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
              control the content visibility and styling.
            </Tabs.Item>
            <Tabs.Item title="Settings" icon={HiAdjustments}>
              This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Settings tab's associated content</span>.
              Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
              control the content visibility and styling.
            </Tabs.Item>
            <Tabs.Item title="Contacts" icon={HiClipboardList}>
              This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Contacts tab's associated content</span>.
              Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
              control the content visibility and styling.
            </Tabs.Item>
          </Tabs>

I want to change base style of icons, text next to them and outline, when clicked from blue to #80143c
Also interested in how can I change other colors, cause classname doesn't work here
here's how it looks like now
-tried to change color with a classname(had no effect, also tried class)
-tried to do it through root(crash)
-tried inner color property(no effect again)

You can write a className for Tabs tag & Iterate Button tag to change styles.
I have added tabsContainer as className below & changed button styles from the parent tag.
<Tabs aria-label="Default tabs" className="tabsContainer" variant="default">
CSS:-


.tabsContainer button:focus {
  color: #80143c;
}




As I already said, all classname props doesn't work at all same as this one. The answer is somwhere in native Flowbite styling props, but I don't know, where exactly

Add div tag. & wrap Tabs inside div like this.
...
write CSS display: none for tabsContainer className. If it works iterate via tabsContainer. If it does not work, check if CSS is imported on the component properly.

For styling Flowbite React components, the component you are using, visit it's page and there will be a "theme" section at the bottom. There you will find it's customization.
In your case, it's in React Tabs - Flowbite
Just copy paste the theme section in you component, change whatever you need to change. Also, since you are using the Underline variant, you can remove the default, pills and fullWidth from the customTheme. You can also remove anything else that you don't or wnt to keep the default style. Your customTheme will be used along with that flowbite component's default styling.


import { Tabs } from "flowbite-react";

export default function YourComponent() {
  const customTheme = {
    base: "flex flex-col gap-2",
    tablist: {
      base: "flex text-center",
      variant: {
        default: "flex-wrap border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700",
        underline:
          "-mb-px flex-wrap border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700",
        pills:
          "flex-wrap space-x-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400",
        fullWidth:
          "grid w-full grid-flow-col divide-x divide-gray-200 rounded-none text-sm font-medium shadow dark:divide-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400",
      },
      tabitem: {
        base: "flex items-center justify-center rounded-t-lg p-4 text-sm font-medium first:ml-0 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-cyan-300 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:text-gray-400 disabled:dark:text-gray-500",
        variant: {
          default: {
            base: "rounded-t-lg",
            active: {
              on: "bg-gray-100 text-cyan-600 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-cyan-500",
              off: "text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-300",
            },
          },
          underline: {
            base: "rounded-t-lg",
            active: {
              on: "active rounded-t-lg border-b-2 border-cyan-600 text-cyan-600 dark:border-cyan-500 dark:text-cyan-500",
              off: "border-b-2 border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-300",
            },
          },
          pills: {
            base: "",
            active: {
              on: "rounded-lg bg-cyan-600 text-white",
              off: "rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-white",
            },
          },
          fullWidth: {
            base: "ml-0 flex w-full rounded-none first:ml-0",
            active: {
              on: "active rounded-none bg-gray-100 p-4 text-gray-900 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-white",
              off: "rounded-none bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white",
            },
          },
        },
        icon: "mr-2 h-5 w-5",
      },
    },
    tabitemcontainer: {
      base: "",
      variant: {
        default: "",
        underline: "",
        pills: "",
        fullWidth: "",
      },
    },
    tabpanel: "py-3",
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        aria-label="Tabs with underline"
        variant="underline"
        theme={customTheme}
      >
        <Tabs.Item active title="Profile" icon={HiUserCircle}>
          This is{" "}
          <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
            Profile tab's associated content
          </span>
          . Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the
          next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content
          visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item title="Dashboard" icon={MdDashboard}>
          This is{" "}
          <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
            Dashboard tab's associated content
          </span>
          . Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the
          next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content
          visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item title="Settings" icon={HiAdjustments}>
          This is{" "}
          <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
            Settings tab's associated content
          </span>
          . Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the
          next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content
          visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item title="Contacts" icon={HiClipboardList}>
          This is{" "}
          <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
            Contacts tab's associated content
          </span>
          . Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the
          next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content
          visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}



